# Dolphin in KDE5 missing some context menu actions (serviceType "KonqPopupMenu/Plugin" not found)

Tags: 15.10, dolphin, kde5

After upgrading to Dolphin with KF5 some context menu action disappeared, including but not limited to my custom actions. When starting Dolphin from CLI it throws this error upon showing a context menu:

```
KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "KonqPopupMenu/Plugin" not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy to workaround:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/kservicetypes5/
cp /usr/share/kde4/servicetypes/konqpopupmenuplugin.desktop ~/.local/share/kservicetypes5/
```

And restart Dolphin. If restarting doesn't help, try regenerating the configuration cache:

```
kbuildsycoca5
```

Source: https://chakraos.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=14189