# No archiving/compressing tool in Dolphin context menu (Kubuntu 15.10)

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, archive, dolphin, plasma-5

Ark is installed but there is no option to create an archive in the file manager's context menu.

[image]

There is a `/usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/ark_servicemenu.desktop`.

Comment: installing ark does the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I anticipated this is related to the "hybrid" state of the present Plasma 5.

Not only upgrade from a KDE4 system to Plasma 5 may disable some features, as presented in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/622465/47206), but installing directly a Plasma 5 system like Kubuntu 15.04 or 15.10 may include similar problems

(as indicated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/622609/47206):

There are KDE4 applications and there are new KF5 applications.The KDE4 parts are looking the service menus from:

```
~/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/ and /usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/
```

The new KF5 service menus are at:

```
~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/ and /usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/*
```

)

But the solution for 15.10 ([here](https://askubuntu.com/a/689777/47206) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/689846/47206)) is different from [the one for 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/622609/47206).

I used the second solution for 15.10, running this command:

```
sudo ln /usr/share/kde4/servicetypes/konqpopupmenuplugin.desktop /usr/share/kservicetypes5/konqpopupmenuplugin.desktop
```

Comment: also: http://askubuntu.com/q/692923/47206

Answer (score 30):

I was missing 'extract' and 'compress' in Dolphin under Ubuntu 16.04 (not Kubuntu!) and fixed it by installing Ark:

```
sudo apt-get install ark
```

Comment: Just used the same fix on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: This is the solution on Zorin OS 16 Lite. Thank you

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS too!

Comment: Works in PopOS 22.04 as well.