# Ubuntu 22.04.3: "Download New Services" in Dolphin is non-responsive and says "QQmlComponent: Component is not ready"

Tags: 22.04, dolphin

I recently did a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04.3. Post that, I installed dolphin from apt by `sudo apt install dolphin`. However, Dolphin Menu -> Configure Dolphin -> Context Menu -> Download New Services is non-responsive. On opening dolphin through a terminal, I see the following messages:

```
Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL
Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL
kf.coreaddons: "Could not find plugin kcms/kcm_trash"
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
```

I have also tried updating the system through `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade`, and `sudo reboot`. But the messages and the non-responsiveness stay as they are.

In case it's relevant, I'm using XFCE4 but I'm able to reproduce the issue on the default Ubuntu desktop too. To get the icons in dolphin, I had to install `qt5ct` and set `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct` in `~/.profile`. Dolphin version is 21.12.3.

Any help to fix this would be appreciated!

PS: I was mainly looking for the Compress and Extract menu in dolphin, but the above looks like a more general problem. I did get the compress and extract menu by `sudo apt install ark` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707665/no-archiving-compressing-tool-in-dolphin-context-menu-kubuntu-15-10).